# CSS Type animation trouble

Tags: css, animation, text, terminal

I'm trying to get the text here to type out as if the webpage is a terminal. Imagine Fallout style. I've been at this all day trying to get the animation to work but just can't get it working. It just types out all of it at once, when I need it line by line.

I am new to this, so my apologies if its simple.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's the fiddly, the layout's gone all funky when I pasted it in...

```css
div.main {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:18px;
    color: white;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 550px;
   animation: type 4s steps(60, end); }

p, ul{
    font-size:18px;
    color: white;
   margin:0;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 550px;
   animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

@keyframes type {
    from { width: 0; }
}

ul,
li,
a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "\003E \003A \0020";
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">

  <div id="main" class="main">
    <h1>PEUR - EXPLORER <span style="font-size:24px">(C)  (P)</span> 2016 \ <br><span style="font-size:24px">[version 1.0]</span><br>
    <p>=================================><br>
  USERNAME: peur_010213<br>
  PASSWORD: ******<br>
  processing request.............<br>
  ...............................<br>
    access granted.<br></p><br>
    <p>=================================><br>
    Welcome to the Mothership.<br>
  All areas accessible.<br>
  Caution advised.<br>
    =================================></p><br>
  <p>C:\admin\dir\010213\peur\xplrr\menu<br><br>
    Please choose one of the following directories<br>to explore:</p><br>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
         <li><a href="explorer.html">Explorer</a></li>
            <li><a href="audio.html">Audio Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html">Video Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="updates.html">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        =================================>
        <p style="font-size:18px">(C)  (P) 2016 PEUR<br>RESTRICTED ACCESS. AUTHORISED PERSONNEL ONLY.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using a script and saving yourself hours of headache: https://macarthur.me/typeit/

Comment: That's because you didn't reveal it line by line- you did the entire page at once. Would agree with looking for a script... unless you want to completely redo your entire page and run the animation line-by-line with the appropriate hand-calculated animation delays.